# Mongo date aggregation operators with ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use the ObjectId as a creation date holder, and running into some problems when trying to do aggregation queries. In particular we want to use the date aggregation operators to group the documents by month, but that operator doesn't work with ObjectId apparently. Is there a way around it, or would I have to start using a separate CreationTime field per document?

Here is a query I was trying -

```
db.People.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        $or: [{"Name":"Random1"}, {"Name":"Random2"}]
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        Name: "$Name",
        Year: {$year: "$_id"},
        Month: {$month: "$_id"}
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {Name: "$Name", Year: "$Year", Month: "$Month"},
        TotalRequests: {$sum:1}
    }
}
```

])

Comment: If the _id is of type ObjectId, it can not work because it is not a date. It is a hash of a date. An the reverse operation is not possible to my knowledge.

Comment: Actually the ObjectID has a [getTimestamp() method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/#ObjectId.getTimestamp), but is not possible use it on AF. You should vote on [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9406) JIRA issue if you really want this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you need to keep a separate field as the Aggregation Framework can not deal with this yet. There is a server ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9406 to implement it so I suggest you vote for it (I just did).